# My exit commands are not working right

Tags: unix

I am not exactly sure if i am using the exits correctly. But when i execute the code with something that prints the usage statement it should stop there.
It should do one or the other. In my case it is doing both.

```
cmd="$1" ## the command to find
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
        then
                echo "usage: ./findcmd command"
fi
exit=1

path=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" " ")
for dir in $path
        do
                if [[ -x "$dir/$cmd" && -r "$dir/$cmd" ]]
                        then
                                echo "$dir/$cmd"
                                exit 0
                fi
        done
echo "$cmd not on $PATH"
exit=0
```

> OUTPUT:

[112]  ./findcmd

usage: ./findcmd command

/usr/local/bin/       **this should not be here

[113]  ./findcmd ping

/usr/bin/ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `exit` correctly to stop the script after your dir/cmd gets printed; try using it that way elsewhere.

Keep in mind that your first `exit`, once correct, will stop the script before the loop whether usage was printed or not.

Comment: why would it not go in the loop if i have the second exit?

Comment: i put everything in the if statement and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be [`exit [n]`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html).

> Within a script, an exit nnn command may be used to deliver an nnn
>   exit status to the shell (nnn must be an integer in the 0 - 255
>   range).

And it should be inside the IF/FOR block.

Like this:

```
cmd="$1" ## the command to find
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]]
    then
        echo "usage: ./findcmd command"
        exit 1
fi

## rest of code to execute if args are correct
```